# Transparent system color in gradient (WPF)

Tags: wpf, xaml, transparent, gradient

How to achieve such effect in XAML:

```
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="BrightSeparatorGradient" StartPoint="0.0, 0.5" EndPoint="1.0, 0.5">
        <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightColorKey}}" /> <!-- But fully transparent -->
        <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightColorKey}}" />
        <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightColorKey}}" /> <!-- But fully transparent -->
    </LinearGradientBrush>
```

I've tried to create two brushes with appropriate color and Opacity set, respectively, to 0.0 and 1.0, but the compiler refused to take Brush as a Color (what is quite logic, on a second thought :)).

Best regards -- Spook.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would create a `MarkupExtension` that takes a `Color` and returns the `Color` with the specified opacity:

```
public class OpacityExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    private readonly Color color;
    public byte Opacity { get; set; } // defaults to 0, so you don't have 
                                      // to set it for the color to be transparent

    public OpacityExtension(Color color)
    {
        this.color = color;           
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return Color.FromArgb(Opacity, color.R, color.G, color.B);
    }
}
```

And then you use it like so:

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="BrightSeparatorGradient" StartPoint="0.0, 0.5" EndPoint="1.0, 0.5">
    <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="{lcl:Opacity {StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightColorKey}}}" />
    <GradientStop Offset=".5" Color="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightColorKey}}" />
    <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="{lcl:Opacity {StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightColorKey}}}" />
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

Comment: I was kinda hoping, that such construction exists and yet it is! XAML does not stop to amaze me. That solves my problem of course, thank you. By the way - just curious - is there a way to achieve the same result with construction <GradientStop><GradientStop.Color>Something here</GradientStop.Color></GradientStop> ?

Comment: You can use a MarkupExtension like that also.  If you want to be able to use it like that, you will need to add a parameterless constructor, and make the Color field a settable property. Then you can do:
<GradientStop><GradientStop.Color><lcl:Opacity Color="{StaticResource ...}" />...

Comment: I get the following error in .Net 3.5 when I specify {Lcl:Opacity {StaticResource {x:Static... "Cannot add content of type 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder' to an object of type ''.  Error at object 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder'". But no error when I specify {lcl:Opacity {x:Static...
Does anyone know the reason for this?

Answer (score -1):

Spook,

Why the following doesn't work for you?

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="BrightSeparatorGradient" StartPoint="0.0, 0.5" EndPoint="1.0, 0.5">
    <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="Transparent" /> 
    <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightColorKey}}" />
    <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="Transparent" /> 
 </LinearGradientBrush>
```

Comment: That doesn't work because that will go from #00FFFFFF to whatever the system color is, which could be something like #FF8080FF.  That will result in a washed out transition from white to blue, instead of only fading in the alpha channel.

Comment: Got it. Then the way suggested by @Abe is quite reasonable.